# Getting return values from a class

Tags: python

How would I get return values in this case. (as I would a function)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.run()
    def run(self):
        return a + b
```

When I do that I get an instance, how would I get a return value?

Thanks
James

Comment: You would get better answers if you mention the underlying problem you are trying to solve. What is the code that uses this, in other words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __call__(self):
        return self.a + self.b

a = A(3, 4)
a() # returns 7
```

It's not clear what you want and why.  `__init__` modifies the self object, but is required to return `None` (i.e. no return).  Anything else will cause a `TypeError`.

EDIT: To avoid creating an instance, you can override `__new__`:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(self,a,b):
        return A.run(a, b);
    @staticmethod
    def run(a, b):
        return a + b
```

You still haven't quite explained why you need this.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do exactly what your code is doing but I don't want an instance.

Comment: If you want a return value and not an instance, why are you trying to use a class instead of a function?

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of calling a type is to create (and return) an instance of that type -- though you may play tricks with `__new__` to work around that, **why**, in the name of everything that matters, would you *want* to code a type that's intrinsically impossible to instantiate by the normal means?!  Looks like you have something "clever" in mind, but, remember, "clever" is *not* a compliment in the Python community... rather, Python is about *simplicity*.  Just use a function (or any other callable, e.g. an instance of a class with a `__call__` method, for advanced but still quite reasonable use cases)!

Comment: Nothing too fancy. All I want is a class function like functionality (that you can use as a function) and if needed 
can call or use some methods aside from the main one.

Comment: @user386: without an instance, the "some methods" you're calling are just functions with some extra complication but without any real benefit over perfectly normal, honest, regular functions.  Just use functions and make your life simpler!